# daily notification in android with alarm manager

Tags: android, service, notifications, alarmmanager

I want to create a reminder system to my android application, i want to give notification to user's phone for each day once. I have looking for any solution to make it using AlarmManager, i have a piece of code like this:

```
public class TaskActivity extends ActionBarActivity ... {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_task);
        periodicNotifier();
    }

    public void periodicNotifier(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, NotifyService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 24*60*60*1000, pendingIntent);
    }

}
```

and this is my NotifyService class

```
public class NotifyService extends Service {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        NotificationManager notifManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent dest = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), TaskActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, dest, 0);

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("My Application")
                .setContentText("Go to application now!")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notif)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .build();

        notifManager.notify(1, notification);
    }
}
```

My problem is:

I want to give the notification every day at morning 00:00, i have tried this code then change the time of my phone to 23:59 then wait it till 00:00 but there's no notification. There's something wrong in my code? Or there's any approach to do that?

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: you have to remove AlarmManager and only use Service 
1)register your service 
2)start your service and pass your current time
3)inside your service you have to put Timer to set the thread(means handler to check every one min)and send your broad cast receiver to you service 
4)your broad cast receiver inside your activity to start and set your notification

Comment: can you give some example code to do that? it would be great, thanks..

Comment: sorry i haven't example like this .... but i have phase this type of  problem and solve it also...just min i give you some code it really help for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to try this code
you have to remove your  AlarmManager , PendingIntent

on your activity set  BroadcastReceiver

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver;
```

and your onCreate() method inside register your mMessageReceiver and start your service

```
registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("time")); 
startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceClockInOut.class));
```

in your // handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String timer = intent.getStringExtra("timer");
         Utils.showNotification(mContext, 1);
    }
};
```

in your service

```
public class ServiceClockInOut extends Service {
    // constant
    public static final long NOTIFY_INTERVAL = 5 * 1000; // 10 seconds

    // run on another Thread to avoid crash
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    // timer handling
    private Timer mTimer = null;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // cancel if already existed
        if (mTimer != null) {
            mTimer.cancel();
        } else {
            // recreate new
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }
        registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter("end_time"));
        // schedule task
        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimeDisplayTimerTask(), 0, NOTIFY_INTERVAL);
    }

class TimeDisplayTimerTask extends TimerTask {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // run on another thread
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // display toast

                    SimpleDateFormat dateTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm aa");
                    String currentDateTime = dateTimeFormat.format(new Date()).toString();
                    String[] startSplit = currentDateTime.split(" ");
                    String CurrentTime = startSplit[1] + " " + startSplit[2].toUpperCase();


                    System.out.println("service start-======   " + CurrentTime + " == " + Constant.mStringStartTime
                            + " == " + Constant.mStringBreakTime);

                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.putExtra("timer", "1");
                        sendBroadcast(intent);



                }

            });
        }

    }
    // handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event
    private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Extract data included in the Intent
            if (mTimer != null)
                mTimer.cancel();
            unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: great answer! thanks for your example, it's really helps!

Comment: This will kill your users battery!